# Show that $E(X 1_A) = E(Y1_A)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d.?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be integrable, real-valued, i.i.d. random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and let $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Is it true that $E(X 1_A) = E (Y1_A)$, or, more generally, are $X1_A$ and $Y1_A$ i.i.d.?
For any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have
\begin{align}
P(X1_A \in B) &= P((\{X1_A \in B\} \cap A) \cup (\{X1_A \in B\} \cap A^c)) = P( \{ X \in B \} \cap A)+ P(\{0 \in B\}\cap A^c) \\
P(Y1_A \in B) &= \ldots = P( \{ Y \in B \} \cap A)+ P(\{0 \in B\}\cap A^c).
\end{align}
This shows that $X1_A$ and $Y1_A$ are i.i.d. if $A$ is independent of $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$. Is it possible to drop this condition? If not, is it possible to conclude the equality for the expectations? If necessary, one can assume that $A \in \sigma(X+Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is in $\sigma(\mathsf{X}+\mathsf{Y})$ then $\mathbf{1}_A=f(\mathsf{X}+\mathsf{Y})$, *a.s.*, for a Borel measurable function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. So $\mathbf{E}[\mathsf{X} \mathbf{1}_A] = \mathbf{E}[\mathsf{X} f(\mathsf{X}+\mathsf{Y})]$ and $\mathbf{E}[\mathsf{Y} \mathbf{1}_A] = \mathbf{E}[\mathsf{Y} f(\mathsf{X}+\mathsf{Y})]$. Since $\mathsf{X}$ and $\mathsf{Y}$ are *iid* that means that the joint distribution of $(\mathsf{X},\mathsf{Y})$, or the distribution of this pair as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same as that of $(\mathsf{Y},\mathsf{X})$. So the expectations are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d then $EX1_A=EY1_A$ need not hold. If $X,Y$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ and $A=\{X>0\}$ then $EX1_A>0$ wheras $EY1_A=(EY)P(X>0)=0$.

The question in the title seems to have a typo. It is very different from the question whether $EX1_A=EY1_A$  holds.